# Knockout style binding does not update Left and Top

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I got the following issue with the knockout style binding: I'm trying to build editor with nodes inside. Also a minimap that should follow the nodes of the editor and display them and their movement on the editor. The positions of the nodes and their "clones" on the minimap should be synchronized.

Html:

```
<div id="minimap">
            <div id="minimap_panner" data-bind="style: { height: dimensions.height + 'px', width: dimensions.width + 'px' }">
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: nodePositions() } -->
                <div class="minimap-node-item" data-bind="style: { left: X + 'px', top: Y + 'px' }"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
ko.applyBindings({
            nodePositions: ko.computed(function () {
                var nodes = model.displayedNodes()();

                return nodes.map(function (node) {
                    return ko.observable(node.Position);
                });
            }),
            dimensions: ko.computed(function () {                     
                return { width: editorElement.scrollWidth, height: editorElement.scrollHeight };
            })
        }, minimapPanner);
```

The **Position** property of each node holds an object { X, Y }.

The issues:

1. When the "clones" are initially rendered on the minimap, their positions are correct. But when I moved a node on the editor, its "clone" on the minimap, does not change its position, even if I see the change on the Knockout context (browser extension). I mean: the context of the "clone" is changed, but its bound style properties (left and top) remain as they are initially.

**Edit: It seems that X and Y are not observable - this may answer the question?!**

*2. (Resolved in the comments) When the **minimap panner** element is initially rendered its bound properties **height** and **width** are not actually bound. Again I can see their values in the Konockout context updated - 
    "dimensions":Object
    height:977
    width:1050
but there is no such styles applied to the element.*

Comment: `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight ` are properties of `Position`?  Are they observables? In the map, you create `Position` as observable, but not its content.

Comment: scrollWidth and scrollHeight are properties of DOM element. 
Position is observable, its properies X,Y are not, but they are updated in the Knockout context, which is what I expect. They are not updated in the markup.

Comment: In this link http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html it says than computed observables depends on one or more observables.  In your `dimensions` computed observable, perhaps `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight ` should be both observables.

Comment: You are right! The binding for the issue 2. will become 

`dimensions: ko.computed(function () {                     
                    return { width:ko.observable(editorElement.scrollWidth), height: ko.observable(editorElement.scrollHeight) };
                })`


and also the binding of the **panner** element will become

`<div id="minimap_panner" data-bind="style: { height: dimensions().height() + 'px', width: dimensions().width() + 'px' }">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that X and Y are not observable, just regular properties?!